# Improving CD Pipeline with Service fabric

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-web-app-service

We have web API's build on *service fabric* as well as some web projects in *web apps* in Azure. We want to easily swap back to the older version of the applications at our deployments and improve the CD pipeline.

So what come up with is ***creating an other app for staging for service fabric*** and route traffic whether that's gradually move users to the instance of the new version, or just flip a switch and send all your traffic to the new version all at once.

> We need a solution that would both support Webapps and Service fabric.
>   Providing patterns and experience for stateful services would be
>   great.

**References**

**A.Web Apps Slot swapping**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-websites-deployment-slots-for-staging-sites/

**B.Continuous Delivery Pipeline**[image]

PS:
I know that swaps don't make sense for stateful services. So rolling upgrades are must if we want to keep your data and keep it consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Azure Api Management, which now has proper support for Service Fabric (check their trello). It should solve the versioning for both as it is external and agnostic to the underlying tech, except it doesn't provide the gradual increase in traffic.

Comment: CI systems such as Octopus will trigger this ?

Comment: And does this mean we should not go to the route of (Service Fabric application upgrade ) Defined here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-tutorial

Comment: I intended API mgmt as a reverse proxy on top of both SF and WebApps. By defining routing rules, you direct traffic to underlying API's.  For instance, you can add a second Application Instance containing V2 of an API and direct traffic to it.      You should definitely use the regular upgrade mechanisms, to ensure rollback upon failures, so you can safely patch a service version.